# Eloquent Query returns nothing where mysql query returns results?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have this eloquent query.

```
    $drops = Drop::with('location')->where('date_id', '=', $date_id)
        ->where('delivered_distance', '>=', 5)
        ->whereHas('delivery', function($q) use($route_id){
            $q->where('route_id', '=', $route_id);
        })->get();
```

Which produces this mysql

```
 { ["query"]=> string(183) "select * from `drops` where `date_id` = ? and `delivered_distance` >= ? and (select count(*) from `deliveries` where `drops`.`delivery_id` = `deliveries`.`id` and `route_id` = ?) >= 1" ["bindings"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> int(5) [2]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Now this returns nothing inside of my code. If I place the data in the correct spot like so

```
select * from `drops` where `date_id` = 10 and `delivered_distance` >= 5 and (select count(*) from `deliveries` where `drops`.`delivery_id` = `deliveries`.`id` and `route_id` = 2) >= 1
```

And run the code I get results back from mysql workbench.

At first I thought it might not like the $date_id and $route_id being strings so I tried type casting.

```
    $drops = Drop::with('location')->where('date_id', '=', (int) $date_id)
        ->where('delivered_distance', '>=', 5)
        ->whereHas('delivery', function($q) use($route_id){
            $q->where('route_id', '=', (int) $route_id);
        })->get();
```

But I still get an empty result from eloquent. Any thoughts?

Here is the code all the code that gets called.

```
public function getAlerts($date_id, $route_id)
{
    $view = View::make('report.alerts');

    $drops = Drop::with('location')->where('date_id', '=', $date_id)
        ->where('delivered_distance', '>=', 5)
        ->whereHas('delivery', function($q) use($route_id){
            $q->where('route_id', '=', $route_id);
        })->get();

    $view->with('drops', $drops);

    return $view;
}
```

Comment: Show the code you execute. This query is fine, so the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Added the requested code. as you can see nothing fancy is going on. If i var_dump($drops); right after the eloquent bit I get object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#331 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: You sure db config is OK? Run `artisan tinker` in cli and play with those queries. There's nothing going on here, problem is somewhere else, again.

Comment: db config is fine. Its only happening in that one bit of code. All else functions perfectly.

Comment: Interesting enough this seems to work fine on staging and not on local host.

Comment: Hard to tell. I never experienced such situation, when the same query run in Laravel returned nothing while in SQL it was ok.

Comment: Yeah, so definitely look in the config, connections etc

Comment: Check error logs maybe there is an error being thrown some where that you're unaware of?

Comment: Are you getting an empty result set or a blank page from `$view`?